# How to see the whole Model object attributes in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run:

```rb
[68] pry(main)> User.first
```

It returns:

```rb
=> #<User:0x411f4>
```

How do I configure rails/ruby to return all the model attributes like it did in rails 6?

ex:

```
=> #<User 
   id: 166,
   email: "hello@statecert.com",
   created_at: "2021-10-05 15:46:44.248514000 +0000",
   updated_at: "2021-10-05 15:47:22.193199000 +0000",
   first_name: "Danika",
   last_name: "LeBlanc", 
   notes: nil
   >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change this behaviour by setting `inspect_mode` to `true`

Open your `.irbrc` config file `nano $HOME/.irbrc`

And set `INSPECT_MODE` to `true`

```rb
IRB.conf[:INSPECT_MODE] = true
```

Examples:

```rb
# IRB.conf[:INSPECT_MODE] = false

=> #<User:0x411f4>
```

```rb
# IRB.conf[:INSPECT_MODE] = true

=> #<User 
   id: 166,
   email: "hello@statecert.com",
   created_at: "2021-10-05 15:46:44.248514000 +0000",
   updated_at: "2021-10-05 15:47:22.193199000 +0000",
   first_name: "Danika",
   last_name: "LeBlanc", 
   notes: nil
   >
```